# How to connecting web API from URL and used that data?

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I complete the [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors#0) about count npm packages download times, now I can use my JSON web api from url, but I don't know how to parse it to rows  with responseToRows() function, I can get data in Logger.log().
My JSON structure is

```
[
    {CODE:value,PRICE:value,QTY:value},
    {CODE:value,PRICE:value,QTY:value}...
]
```

The value  I wish is:

```js
function responseToRows(requestedFields, parsedResponse) {
  // Transform parsed data and filter for requested fields
  return response.map(function() {
    var row = [];
    requestedFields.asArray().forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field.getId()) {
        case 'CODE':
          return row.push(CODE);
        case 'PRICE':
          return row.push(PRICE);
        case 'QTY':
          return row.push(QTY);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}
```

but I don't know how to `row.push()` in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few additional changes that you need to make to the original function from the tutorial:

- Probably you won't use the `requestedFields` parameter as it is used in the tutorial, since it's an object based on what is used by Data Studio. So you can remove it and just go over the keys of each object you're passing (see code below).
- The `parsedResponse` argument is not used in the function and you're using `response` instead, so you need to change the argument's name as well.
- The function inside `map` is missing an argument name that will be used when pushing values to the row inside the `switch` (see code below). I named it `transaction`, but you can use another name if you want.

Doing these modifications, the code becomes something like the following:

```
function responseToRows(response) {
  return response.map(function(transaction) {
    var row = [];

    Object.keys(transaction).forEach(function (field) {
      switch (field) {
        case 'CODE':
          return row.push(transaction.CODE);
        case 'PRICE':
          return row.push(transaction.PRICE);
        case 'QTY':
          return row.push(transaction.QTY);
        default:
          return row.push('');
      }
    });
    return { values: row };
  });
}
```

And then you can test it like this:

```
function test() {
  const testData = [
    {CODE:1,PRICE:1,QTY:1},
    {CODE:2,PRICE:2,QTY:2},
    {CODE:3,PRICE:3,QTY:3},
    {CODE:4,PRICE:4,QTY:4},
  ];
  Logger.log(responseToRows(testData));
}
// Result:
//[{values=[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}, 
// {values=[2.0, 2.0, 2.0]}, 
// {values=[3.0, 3.0, 3.0]}, 
// {values=[4.0, 4.0, 4.0]}
//]
```

Also, if you plan to write that result to a sheet, then it's probably better to have it in a 2-dimension array format, so you'd have to change `return { values: row };` to just `return row;`.